# ReportLab - Place two paragraphs on same line with space inbetween

Tags: python, reportlab

Please do not mark this as duplicate. I have seen some questions on SO with similar titles but they don't help me in this situation.

I want my two paragraphs to appear like this.

`Paragraph One with one kind of style` `Paragraph two with different kind of style`

I tried the below code but the table leaves too much gap between the two paragraphs. Like this

`Para1 [padding...................]`         `Para2 [padding...................]`

But I want it like:

`Para1` `Para2`

I just want text side by side like **TEXT1** *text2*. It doesn't have to be as table.

My code is:

```
stuff1= Paragraph(str(stuff.1).encode('utf-8'), st1)
stuff2= Paragraph(str(stuff.2).encode('utf-8'), st2)
table_stuff = Table([[suff1, stuff2]], colWidths=None)
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
stuff = '<font size="18">'+var1+'</font>'+ '<font size="15" color="gray">'+' '+var2+'</font>'
stuffPara = Paragraph(str(suff).encode('utf-8'), st)

table_stuff = Table([[stuffPara]], colWidths=None)
```